# Error while executing shell script in Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am currently new to shell scripting and stuck with a problem for which i need help from you guys.

I am running a shell script processmainjk.ksh at the linux command promt.
This script internally calls another script with this entry

```
$PROC_BIN_DIR/admin/processsub.ksh -c $PROC_CONFIG_DIR/daily/processsub.cfg -m tkp
```

The processsub.cfg has name value entries like "prc_log_dir    ${PROCESS_LOG_DIR}" and these are being read internally by the script processsub.ksh with the code below

```
while read name value
do
   value=`eval "echo $value"`
   case "$name" in
     prc_log_dir) LOGDIR=$value;;
     prc_arch_dir) ARCHIVE_DIR=$value;;
 esac
done < $config_file


if [ ! -d ${LOGDIR} ]; then
  echo "ERROR:($PNAME)(Invalid or missing $LOGDIR)"
  exit 1
fi
```

where the $config_file is processsub.cfg. Now i am not sure what "read name value" is doing in the script but i am guessing its reading name value par from the config file.
The if block after the while loop throws the error. Debugged it separately in the command prompt and the ${LOGDIR} is being picked but i don't know why its not working when i run the script.

When i ran this script for the first time without any changes it ran successfully. Later i made some changes in config file processap.cfg and modified its permission as it was not allowing me to edit and when i ran it again this time it is giving me below error

```
 /testmac/bin/admin/processsub.ksh[52]: eval[1]: meaning: not found [No such file or directory]
)RROR:(/testmac/bin/admin/processsub.ksh)(Invalid or missing /testmac/bin/admin
```

If you see the line number in the error "52" it is pointing to value=`eval "echo $value"` in the while loop. Not sure about this error but the directory /testmac/bin/admin is present in the file system. running the same script with the previous changes is giving the same error.

Can somebody help me with this issue and let me know how i can resolve it. being stuck with this error for a long time now.

**Update:**

Thanks a lot guys for your help. The actual issue was that the config file had got messed up when i edited it in windows and transferred it to linux box using FileZilla. now did all the operations on linux prompt itself and everything works fine

Thanks

Comment: What is `value=\`eval "echo $value"\`` supposed to do?

Comment: Did you edit the file on a Windows machine or otherwise convert the file to DOS line-endings? (See the first item on the bash tag wiki.)

Comment: @ Etan Reisner yes i just edited the config file in windows machine changied its permissions on Linux machine as it not allowing me to do the same. i had transferred the file using FileZilla to Linux machine before changing permissions

Comment: @ Biffen value=`eval "echo $value"` should get evaluated to the directory path but somehow its null or blank when i echo its value

Comment: use `dos2unix file` to remove extra Ctrl-M line-ending chars introduced when processing in Windows. This will mess up scripts and data. Good luck.

Comment: @vikeng21 `value=\`eval "echo $value"\`` will set the value of `$value` to the value of `$value`, i.e. it doesn't really do anything (except it might change some whitespace). To what do you refer by ‘the directory path’?

Comment: @ Biffen have updated the question. what i mean by directory path is /testmac/bin/admin this should be the value. but the if condition is failing everytime for it. debugging it separately by exporting the if [ ! -d ${LOGDIR} ]; then works fine. don't know whats the cause of this issue

Comment: @ shellter have updated question with more code. doing a cat filename in the command prompt does not show me Ctrl-M or any special characters. how can i determine the same

Comment: Your problem was already diagnosed in @EtanReisner's comment above and confirmed by shellter. You are wasting your time, and ours. Fix the line endings.

Comment: @vikeng21 That line still looks highly suspicious. Have a look at Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer, it contains a few points that I failed to realise. Put an `echo $value` before *and* after the line to see what really happens. And you might want to add a `set -ex` at the top of your script. And use http://www.shellcheck.net (FYI: If you skip the space after the @ people will actually be notified about your replies.)

Comment: @Biffen thanks a lot for your help. The actual issue was that the config file had got messed up when i edited it in windows and transferred it to linux box using FileZilla. now did all the operations on linux prompt itself and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$value` contains something such as ";meaning foo". This means that `"echo $value"` expands to `"echo ;meaning foo"`. And when you evaluate this you first run `echo` with no arguments, and then you run `meaning foo`. But `meaning` isn't a valid command, so the script blows up.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. The actual issue was that the config file had got messed up when i edited it in windows and transferred it to linux box using FileZilla. now did all the operations on linux prompt itself and everything works fine